# Issue with Group email address domain when create a new Microsoft 365 Group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a strage "issue".
When I crate a new Microsoft 365 Group on azure the default Group email address domain is @mydomain.onmicrosoft.com and I can't change it.
When the group is create, the Group email address domian changes in @mydomain.com.
My goal is to create a Microsoft 365 group with Group email address domain @mydomain.com and at the end of the day this is done..but I can't understand why I can't change the domain in first place and why it change automatically.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the same on my environment and it was the same for me . This is because when you are creating a Azure AD tenant , you by-default get a Microsoft Domain which will be the primary domain like `M365Bxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com` but when you create a custom domain as `mydomain.com` and verify it and then make it as primary , the Microsoft domain can't be deleted and the custom domain get assigned as primary domain for the Azure AD .

[image]

So, When you create a Group it bydefault takes the Microsoft Provided Domain for your AzureAD in that dialog box and it cannot be changed.

[image]

But When you click on create , in the backend mapping it takes the primary domain like `group@azure_ad_primarydomain` instead of `group@domain.onmicrosoft.com` which is provided by Microsoft. Basically it will automatically get changed to the primary domain assigned to the Azure AD after you click on create.

[image]

[image]

Comment: AnsumanBal-MT, thanks a lot for detailed answer!

Comment: Glad to be of help @chiprule..

Answer (score 0):

In my case requirement was:

> Create M365 Group with mail enabled using azure portal or `New-MgGroup` Powershell, set the email domain as Custom Domain instead of vality domain (*.onmicrosoft.com)

If you have setup the custom domain correctly, you can instead configure it from [M365 portal](https://portal.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home#/groups):

Steps:

1. Login to M365 Admin Portal & Navigate to Active teams and groups
2. In *Teams & Microsoft 365 Groups* Tab click *+ Add a Microsoft 365 Group*

[image]

3. Follow the wizard. On Settings tab if you have set custom domain as you default domain, then the domain will be auto-selected.

[image]